# How can I modify this script to also exclude accounts that contain the word "admin"

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to come up with a PowerShell script that will give me an accurate count of the number of user profiles that are on a pc. Excluding any pc that has less that 5 accounts. I don't use PowerShell that often so I don't know the correct syntax for it.

```
$excludedAccounts = @('admin', "Administrator", "Domain Admins", "LocalAdmin")

$userProfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$count = 5

($profile in $userProfiles) {
(-not ($excludedAccounts -contains $profile)) {
$count++
}
}

Write-Host "Number of user profiles (excluding domain and local admin accounts): $count"
```

This works pretty well, but it isn't what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you forgot a `foreach` and an `if`, but actually you can do this with a simple `Where-Object` clause in which you do a regex `-notmatch` on string `admin` like this:

```
# get all user profile folder names except for those that have the word 'admin' in it
$userProfiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch 'admin' }).Name
Write-Host "Number of user profiles (excluding domain and local admin accounts): $($userProfiles.Count)"
```

If you need to do this on multiple computers, use `Invoke-Command` like so:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter your admin credentials here'
$computers = 'pc01', 'pc02', 'pc03'  # the list of computers to probe
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    # get all user profile folder names except for those that have the word 'admin' in it
    $userProfiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch 'admin' }).Name
    # now output an object to collect in the $result variable
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName'       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        'Non-Admin Profiles' = $userProfiles.Count
    }
}
```

Then if you want to see what computers have 5 or more non admin profiles for instance you do

```
$result | Where-Object { $_.'Non-Admin Profiles' -ge 5 }
```

Comment: That is actually really good, I think we have around 900 workstations at the moment. We are trying to determine which ones are "multi-user" based on the number of profiles associated with each machine. Minus any of the admin accounts that would have logged in at some point.

Comment: @Sloan With that many computers, I would do this in a number of steps and make sure they are all reachable (not offline) first. BTW, being new here, may I point you to the [tour] where you can see how to mark a question 'done' if an answer solved your problem. That way others can benefit as well